# what does function "int (*function())[10];" mean?

Tags: c++, c

I read a piece of code and find there is a function like that.

```
int (*function())[10]{
 ...
}
```

I am confused. What does this function mean and what will it return?

Comment: http://cdecl.org and http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: Also see some tutorial about function pointers like http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: @user1929959: but function pointers don't have anything to do with anything in the question?

Comment: I'm wondering if my answer helped. Did it? (I hope it did) :-)

Answer (score 16):

It is the definition of a function that returns a pointer to an array of 10 integers.

Remember that the return value is a *pointer*, not an actual array. Arrays cannot be returned from functions. Per paragraph 8.3.5/8 of the Standard:

> Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function, although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to such things

Here's a simple example of how you would use it:

```
int arr[10];     // an array of 10 int
int (*ptr)[10]; // pointer to an array of 10 int

int (*function())[10] // function returning a pointer to an array of 10 int
{
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int (*p)[10] = function(); // assign to the pointer
}
```

You can use this wherever you would normally use a pointer. But note that there are better alternatives than pointers altogether, like `std::shared_ptr<std::array<T, N>>` or `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>`.

Comment: Is that even useful? :-| I don't mean the answer, I mean specifying that the return value is a pointer to an array of size 10.

Comment: @NikosC., I'd return a `std::array<int, 10>`, or change it appropriately if you actually need to change the original.

Comment: @NikosC. Yes, we're returning a pointer just like any other object. Another advantage is that it will only compile if the array size is 10, no type decay is involved.

Comment: @0x499602D2 And how would I declare a function that returns a pointer to a size 10 array? In other words, what is the function signature that this function pointer is compatible with?

Comment: @NikosC. This has frequent use in C, but in C++ you can use array aggregates like `std::array`.

Comment: @NikosC., You can't actually return a native array.

Comment: @NikosC. The Standard says that arrays or functions cannot be returned from functions.

Comment: @chris Yeah, that's why ask. What can be assigned to that function pointer? If nothing can be assigned to it, then we're back to my original comment: "is that even useful?"

Comment: @NikosC., It's returning a *pointer* to an array. That's still ok, if a little more confusing than it has to be.

Comment: @NikosC. `int (*arr)[10] = function();`

Comment: `function` is uninitialized at this moment. You have to assign it a value first. That value has to be the address of a function. What function though? This, for example, doesn't work: `int[10] foo();` nor this: `int foo()[10];`.

Comment: @NikosC. The value can't be a function pointer, you have a misconception. The pointer to the array that it *returns* is its value. For example, [see this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fa8b313faef65a76dfa5194478b2de14-5f3eac91c5efc8eb86eae865cc530730).

Comment: @NikosC.: `function` is not a pointer.  It is the name of the function.

Comment: `typedef int arr10[10]; typedef arr10 *parr10; parr10 foo();` or something similar.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ah, I totally misread the answer :-/ Sorry. Somehow I understood it to be a pointer to a function returning a pointer to an array of 10 integers. Oops!

Comment: @NikosC. off the top of my head I believe that would be `int (*(*f()))[10];`

Comment: No, actually it is `int (*(*f())())[10];`

Answer (score 8):

The way to read it is to find the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that `()` and `[]` bind before `*`, so `*a[]` is an array of pointers, `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array, `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, and `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function.  Thus,

```
      function          - function
      function()        - is a function
     *function()        - returning a pointer
    (*function())[10]   - to a 10-element array
int (*function())[10]   - of int
```

Comment: Never came across functions returning arrays (or pointers to arrays before); the '[]' at the right looks weird. I guess the next step in complexity would be declaring a pointer to this function.

Comment: The other way to look at it is to substitute `function()` with a symbol `f`, giving `int (*f)[10]`; now it doesn't look so weird.

Comment: Of course, it makes perfect logic sense syntax-wise; It's just that you can code for years without coming across this case, it caught me off-guard... I guess you learn something every day ;)

Answer (score 0):

it means that is a function pointer and the argument is void and return int[10]